# Login "Lightbox" for specific category content

Tags: categories, login

There's a specific category on my website that should be restricted to teachers only using login.
However, I don't want to hassle the teachers with the not so welcoming admin Wordpress offers.
I would like to offer a "lightbox" that's basically a login that doesn't automatically forward to the admin, but only makes the teachers category content available.
Do you know any plugin that allows that?
Thanks,
Sarit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know about a plugin that does that for you but you can use the WordPress native Thickbox:

[image]

First include the Thickbox script and style in your category only if the user is not logged in (simply copy/paste  in your theme's functions.php file)

```
function add_thickbox_script_and_style(){
    if(is_category('YOUR_CATEGORY') && !is_user_logged_in()){
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
        wp_enqueue_script('thickbox',null,array('jquery'));
        wp_enqueue_style('thickbox.css', '/'.WPINC.'/js/thickbox/thickbox.css', null, '1.0');
    }
}
add_action('init','add_thickbox_script_and_style');
```

Then open up your category.php (or archive.php depending on your theme , or even better is a custom file for that category  `category-id.php`) and add this code before the loop:

```
if (is_category('YOUR_CATEGORY') && !is_user_logged_in()){
    echo '<div id="lform" style="display:none;">';
    wp_login_form();
    echo '</div>';
    echo 'Please <a class="thickbox" href="#TB_inline?height=200&width=200&inlineId=lform">Login</a> to see the content';
}else{


//your loop goes here

}
```